# Pascal bubble sort print each sorted line

Tags: sorting, pascal, bubble-sort

I have my bubble sorting algorithm which works correctly but I want to set it up so it prints each line in the process of the final output(19 lines).I have tried almost everything, but it doesn't print correctly:

```
program Bubble_Sort;

const N = 20;

var
  d : array[1..N] of integer;
var
  i,j,x : integer;
begin

  randomize;
  for i := 1 to N do d[i] := random(100);
  writeln('Before sorting:'); writeln;
  for i := 1 to N do write(d[i], ' ');
  writeln;

  for j := 1 to N - 1 do
    for i := 1 to N - 1 do
      write(d[i], ' ');
      if d[i] > d[i+1] then 
      begin
        x := d[i]; d[i] := d[i+1]; d[i+1] := x;
      end;


  writeln('After sorting:'); writeln;
  for i := 1 to N do write(d[i], ' ');
  writeln;
end.
```

Comment: Please show what the current output is and an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer loop in the center of your code, the `for j ...` loop runs for each bubble iteration. That is where you want to output the state of the sorting. Because you thus have more than one statement within that `for j ...` loop, you must also add a `begin .. end` pair:

```
for j := 1 to N - 1 do
begin
  //one round of sorting
  //display result so far
end;
```

The sorting is ok as you have it, except when you added the `write(d[i], ' ');` presumably to output the sort result for one iteration, you changed the execution order to become totally wrong.
Remove the `write(d[i], ' ');` from where it is now.

To display the sorting result after each iteration add a new `for k ...` loop and a `writeln;`

```
for k := 1 to N do
  write(d[k], ' ');
writeln;
```

Final sorting and progress display should be structured like:

```
for j := 1 to N - 1 do
begin
  for i := 1 to N - 1 do
  // one round of sorting
  for k := 1 to N - 1 do
  // output result of one sorting round
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful.

Comment: @anna:  When an answer has helped you, like Tom's has, please get into the habit of "accepting" it by clicking the "tick" icon next to its top lefthand side.